# how to handle xhr blob post in nodejs

Tags: node.js, post, express, xmlhttprequest

client code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/frame', true);
xhr.send(blob);
```

server code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false,limit: '50mb'}));
app.post('/frame', function (req, resp) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

this gives PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters
adding

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

doesn't solve the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the content of `blob`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your blob variable is not really url encoded form data and just any kind of content. Then at the server side you can just read the request stream as it comes in. Remember that the `req` variable on your `http.Server.request` event handler is a readable stream. This will remove any size limit imposed by the `body-parser` middleware. Keeping your original client code then your server code would be:

```
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false,limit: '50mb'}));

app.post('/frame', function (req, resp) {
  req.on('readable', function(){
    console.log(req.read());
  });
});
```

Processing request as it is streamed in is a good idea even for structured data if the content is too big. For example in the past I had hit performance problems when i use `body-parser#json` middleware with big json requests and solve the issue removing the `body-parser#json` middleware and using [oboe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oboe) for parsing the streamed input.

Comment: can you provide few references for the same.

Comment: the req param pass to `request` event handlers are instances of class https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage and as per the docs that class is a readable stream. With that info you can search for the nodes stream doc and use the readable stream api as in the example code (registering a `readable` event handler)

Answer (score 2):

Your `blob` variable exceed the limit size set in the server. You must set a number always bigger than the client data (`blob`).

the client:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/frame', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(blob);
```

the server:

```
// set limit with a value always bigger than the client data
var upperBound = '1gb';
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: upperBound}));
app.post('/frame', function (req, resp) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Remember to set the `content-type` and call the appropriate `bodyParser.method()`. For example, if the blob contains an image, the content-type should be `application/octet-stream` and the `bodyParser` method to be called is `raw()`. Otherwise the server will throw errors.