# How to handle encoded base64 audio and resend to google?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

I recorded audio from the browser using the microphone,encoded base64, and sent to my node.js app which is suppose to send the base64 data to google speech to text api and then send me a transcription. I am confused on how to handle the data from the post response and then send it google.

Here is what I have so far client-side ajax post:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = function() {

        var fd = new FormData();
        base64data = reader.result;
        fd.append('rawaudio', base64data);
        console.log(base64data)
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/send',
          data: fd,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
        }).done(function(err,data) {
          console.log(data)
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
```

express node.js

```
app.post('/send',(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.body.rawaudio)
 })
```

I get undefined for

```
console.log(req.body.rawaudio)
```

But I know the data is sent because

```
console.log(base64data)
```

is defined

Comment: b64 string taken of PCM audio as a way to post to express is kind of inefficient in comparison to doing encoding on the client, POSTING a binary to express , THEN going to b64 string for the POST to google cloud... realize that is not the question...

Comment: ans here may help u get your very large string out of the post.body .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418921/how-to-handle-xhr-blob-post-in-nodejs  . i just implemented node wrapper for cloud speech but using diff approach..  from the mic, i encoded to 16K opus using 'record.js' opus package. I fetch POST'd that blob to express midware rawbodyParser to get the binary body from the POST. then converted that to b64 string on server , wrapped the POST to google api and returned their response back to my client-side.

Answer (score 0):

exporting the wav to blob and then sending it to NodeJS and saving it to DB for further use . (in my case Mongo)

```
function sendToBackEnd(blob){
var blob = blob;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

reader.onloadend = function() {
blob = reader.result.toString();
console.log(blob)

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
fd.append('data', blob);
// fd.append('data', blob);
$.ajax({
    url: '/recordings',
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
}
```

}

and then on your NodeJs side:

```
app.post('/recordings',function(req,res){
var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(req, function(err, file) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    var data=file.data;
    newRecording={content:data}
    Recording.create(newRecording,function(err,Recording){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(Recording)
        }
    });

});
```

});